# How to place text in an image with an a href tag

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In bootstrap 4 we can add classes to get text placed over an image like so:

```
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-3 text-center d-flex align-items-center">
        <img class="img-fluid position-relative mx-auto" src="//placehold.it/360x360" alt="">
        <h3 class="w-100 position-absolute text-danger my-auto">Title</h3>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

But when I add an a tag it does not work anymore:

```
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-3 text-center d-flex align-items-center">
      <a href="#0">
        <img class="img-fluid position-relative mx-auto" src="//placehold.it/360x360" alt="">
        <h3 class="w-100 position-absolute text-danger my-auto">Title</h3>
      </a>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Here's a codeply to display the issue: https://www.codeply.com/p/ADqP51VnTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .. use class d-flex align-items-center at a tag.

```html
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-3 text-center d-flex align-items-center">
        <img class="img-fluid position-relative mx-auto" src="//placehold.it/360x360" alt="">
        <h3 class="w-100 position-absolute text-danger my-auto">Title</h3>
     </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <a href="#0" class="text-center d-flex align-items-center">
        <img class="img-fluid position-relative mx-auto" src="//placehold.it/360x360" alt="">
        <h3 class="w-100 position-absolute text-danger my-auto">Title</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Yup, that did it! Couldn't think of adding it to the a tag instead of the column. Thank you.